# числа с плавающей точкой oracle

Tags: oracle

С одной в оракл таблицы пытаюсь инсертить n-ное количество записей в другой.В первой таблице есть поле с типом varchar2 а во второй она number теперь в первой таблице данные есть с плавающей точкой и когда их инсертю ругается на тип потому что в number нельзя ставить число с плавающей точкой

```
substr(str, 1, instr(str,'.')-1)
ROUND(str) 
TRUNC(str)
```

они не помогли первое если в поле целое число его пропускает а вместо него ставит `null`

Comment: формат чисел в varchar2 какой, там разделитель всегда именно точка. И у вас в сессии разделитель для чисел то же точка ? И number просто или вроде number(13,2) и главное какой итог вы хотите получить, именно целую часть. И не пробовали ли вы явно приводить тип round(TO_NUMBER(str)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так должно сработать

```
nvl(substr(str, 1, instr(str,'.')-1),str)
```